# Open covers with a finite subcover for the natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can anybody give me three open covers for $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers, each of them having one of these properties:

(1) a finite number of sets,

(2) an open cover with an infinite number of sets that has a finite subcover,

(3) an open cover that has no finite subcover.

I think the first one does not exist because there exists no maximum element for $\mathbb{N}$.

For the second one the set $\{(0,\infty),(0,n)\}$.

The last one I don't know.

Comment: For $(1)$, you are correct, take $(n)_{n \geq 1}$, this sequence does not converge (ah I didn't read your latter question, but jdc's single cover is good).  Either I am reading this wrong or $(2)$ is exactly the same as $(1)$. For $(3)$, I assume you mean a finite subcover for $N$? You already showed this does not exist in $(1)$, so I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: Open in what topology? I am used to seeing $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the discrete topology. 1) The trivial cover $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ has only a finite number of sets. You've already figured this out, given your answer to the second question. 3) What about using only finite sets?

Comment: not topology, but an open cover with an infinite number of sets is could be something like the Set (-3,n) for the interval (-3,4) as an example.  For 3, it could be something like (-3,4-1/n) for the interval (-3,4) or something

Comment: @Jack, jdc is asking what metric are you using. If that helps.

Comment: We have not defined metrics at all, trust me I know

Comment: Then it probably isn't the discrete topology then. But I am still trying to understand what $(3)$ is asking.

Comment: look in the example I gave you, its basically an open cover that doesn't cover all of the elements, but acts like it does

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so can you post the original question?

Comment: I mean not a homework question, but that is pretty much my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to clarify your notation.

For one, it is not clear whether $N$ means $\{1,2,3,...\}$ or $\{0,1,2,3,....\}$.  I will assume that the first is the case, unless you indicate otherwise.

For your answer to the second question, I assume you mean
$$
\{(0,n): n \in N\} \cup (0,\infty)
$$
Which is indeed an open cover of $\{1,2,3,...\}$ that has a finite subcover, assuming you're using the standard definitions for open and closed sets of real numbers.

From your answer for the second, it should be clear that there is an answer to the first.

For the third, consider the collection
$$
\{(0,n): n \in N\}
$$
which you were working with anyway.  Is this an open cover of $N$?  Is any finite subcollection also a cover of $N$?

Comment: Isn't it universal that the natural numbers, as stated in the question, from {1,2,3...}. If they are not, then I guess everything online saying they are from {1,2,3..} is incorrect?

Comment: @Jack it is often the case that the natural numbers include $0$; it generally depends on the whims of the author. See [the third paragraph here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) and [the first paragraph here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)